# Java warning with implementing Comparable

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Collections.sort on a ArrayList of custom objects, but I'm getting a warning and I can't figure out why

```
Warning: Type safety: Unchecked invocation 
sort(ArrayList<CharProfile>) of the generic method sort(List<T>) 
of type Collections
```

With this code:

```
ArrayList<CharProfile> charOccurrences = new ArrayList<CharProfile>();

...

Collections.sort(charOccurrences);
```

And here's my method:

```
public class CharProfile implements Comparable {

...

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {

        if (this.probability == ((CharProfile)o).getProbability()) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (this.probability > ((CharProfile)o).getProbability()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the "else" doing at the start of the "compareTo()" method?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Comparable should be implemented with type safety, here it is `<CharProfile>`.

```
public class CharProfile implements Comparable<CharProfile>{
       @Override
       public int compareTo(CharProfile cp) {
       ...
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using generics, so make the type you pass to the method `CharProfile` instead of `Object`.

I'd also recommend rearranging the comparisons as shown, in case that probability is a double.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(CharProfile o) {

        if (this.probability < o.getProbability()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.probability > o.getProbability()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Noticed that already answered, but here is my input anyway :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CharProfile implements Comparable <CharProfile>{
  public void doStuff(){
    List<CharProfile> charOccurrences = new ArrayList<CharProfile>();
    Collections.sort(charOccurrences);
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(CharProfile o) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: is the compareTo() you have written valid?