# Arraylist : uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: android, casting, warnings, unchecked

I have two warning in my app that prevent me for an "uses unchecked or unsafe operations". I tried to understand another posts but I do not understand at all what happens so I'm still at the starting point...

One in my Adapter class (the warning in on "(ArrayList) results.values") :

```
arrayList = (ArrayList<Sound>) results.values;
```

[image]

And another in my Activity where I am using the arraylist (the warning is on "Collections.sort") :

```
        Collections.sort(names);
```

[image]

Can you explain me what does it means and how to solve it please ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Just asking, which IDE you are using, It is not Android Studio!

Comment: BTW it is just an warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: See this answer for same. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44078128/6891563

Comment: I'm on Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `results.values` is apparently `Object`, so casting it to an `ArrayList<Sound>` is dangerous since its run-time type could be incompatible with that type. If `result.values` is always an `ArrayList<Sound>` and you have the ability to change its type, then simply change it to `ArrayList<Sound>`. If you absolutely don't have the ability to change the type and you are absolutely certain that the cast will be valid at run-time, then you can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above that line to suppress the warning.

I don't know what the type of `names` is in your excerpt, but it's likely that its `compareTo()` method has a similarly unsafe cast, due to underspecifying the parameter type. Look for a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122718/java-warning-with-implementing-comparable).